# String to hex splitting

Tags: qt, qstring

I am having a QString :

```
QString str = "1000140035";
```

I want to extract each byte from above string like this :--

```
Unsigned char a = 0x10
Unsigned char b = 0x00
Unsigned char c = 0x14
Unsigned char d = 0x00
Unsigned char e = 0x35
```

Please suggest how to do this ... tried but failed many times.

Comment: it's always better to show an attempt (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QByteArray::fromHex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromHex) + [`QString::toLatin1()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1)

```
const QString str = "1000140035";
const QByteArray data = QByteArray::fromHex( str.toLatin1() );
unsigned char a = data[0];
unsigned char b = data[1];
unsigned char c = data[2];
unsigned char d = data[3];
unsigned char e = data[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for? The code will parse an arbitrary length hexadecimal string and return an array of 2-digit hexadecimal numbers along with their count. It allocates memory for the result, so it is your responsibility to release it afterwards. The number of extracted numbers is returned through the third argument.

```
#include <QString>
#include <cmath>

unsigned HexToNum(char c)
{
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return c - '0';

    if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        return 15 + c - 'A';

    if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        return 15 + c - 'a';

    //Non hex char passed, return 0
    return 0;
}

void ExtractBytes(const QString& hexString, unsigned char*& result, int& resultNumbersCount)
{
    resultNumbersCount = static_cast<int>(ceil(hexString.length() / 2));
    result = new unsigned char[resultNumbersCount];

    int i, j = -1;
    for(i = 0; i < resultNumbersCount; ++i)
        result[i] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < hexString.length(); ++i)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            ++j;

        result[j] = result[j] * 16 + HexToNum(hexString.at(i).toLatin1());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are modifying a local `result` argument, so you should pass it as a reference to pointer or as a pointer to pointer. In your case, variable `result` will not be changed. It is a memory leak + error in logic, because result of `ExtractBytes` method will be unavailable.

Comment: @SaZ Good point, my bad, result is now passed as a reference to the destination pointer

Comment: Anyway, you have a lot of hand-made magic, that may be done with Qt. Check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`QString::toInt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt) and set the base to 16 to convert a hex-string to int (or [`QString::toUInt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUInt)).

```
QString str = "1000140035";
while(!str.isEmpty())
{
    unsigned char byte = str.left(2).toInt(0, 16);
    // do something with byte, store it somewhere or whatever...
    str.remove(0, 2);
}
```

Comment: Don't. Thuga is cool, but it is a hand-made code with a big overhead (unnesessary string modification). There are existing methods in Qt for such things....

Comment: @Katoch I'd go with SaZ's solution. It stores all the bytes in a `QByteArray` so you don't have to do it manually.